# Problem with accessing reference in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Unable to add new element (node) to `ArrayList`

```
Node N = new Node(5,"Sandeep");
Node N1 = new Node(5,"qwert");
```

In below line I am getting null pointer exception

```
N.children.add(N1)
```

Code:

```
class Node {
    public int val;
    public String data;
    public ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node(int val, String data) {
        this.val = val;
        this.data = data;
        ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
}

public class Nary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
       // ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node N = new Node(5,"Sandeep");
        Node N1 = new Node(5,"qwert");
        N.children.add(N1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are recreating the children array inside the constructor, not initializing the class children array, so it's null.

Comment: This is enough in constructor `children = new ArrayList<Node>();` you are declaring local variable in constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this in your code

```
class Node {

    public int val;
    public String data;
    public ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node(int val, String data) {
        this.val = val;
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node constructor you are creating new local attribute of children
If you change below in constructor its will works fine
 this.children = new ArrayList();